# How to create today, tomorrow and yesterday with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

first of all I have searched the forum for getting an answer to my problem. I am creating a weekly schedule with PHP & MySQL and the problem is that I can not figure out how to setup the case statement when the actual day is Sunday and I need to set Monday as Tomorrow.
Here is my simple MySQL table week

```
Fields: dayid(int,primary,auto-increment),day(varchar(25))
Data: (1,'Monday'),(2,'Tuesday'),(3,'Wednesday'),(4,'Thursday'),
      (5,'Friday'),(6,'Saturday'),(7,'Sunday');
```

Here is my php code:

```
$today = date("N");
$query = "SELECT *,case when dayid = '$today' THEN 'Today'
                        when dayid = '$today' + 1 THEN 'Tomorrow'
                        when dayid = '$today' - 1 THEN 'Yesterday'
                        ELSE day END days FROM week ";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo '<p>'.$r['days'].'</p>'; }
```

Like I wrote before I can not figure out how to set it up so when $today = 7 (Sunday) that Monday will say Tomorrow and the other way around so when it´s Monday that it says yesterday instead of Sunday. Hopefully someone can help me solve this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `('$today' + 1) % 7`

Comment: @juergend That would only work if he used 0-6, not 1-7. And it doesn't work for the subtraction case, because `-1%7` is `-1`, not `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IF` to wrap around at the end of the week:

```
CASE dayid
    WHEN $today THEN Today
    WHEN IF($today = 7, 1, $today + 1) THEN 'Tomorrow'
    WHEN IF($today = 1, 7, $today - 1) THEN 'Yesterday'
    ELSE day
END days
```